# Spring OAuth2 Password Flow keeps failing

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, kotlin, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to enable OAuth2 Password Flow in my Spring Boot application, however, I just can't get it to run, no matter what I try.

There following are my configurations.
For the `TokenStore` I configured a `JdbcTokenStore` bean and the `UserDetailsService` is simply loading the user from my custom user tables.
I also added the the property `security.oauth2.resource.filter-order=3`.

For Spring Boot I'm using `2.0.0.RELEASE` and for Spring Security `2.3.0.RELEASE`.

Both the authorization server and the resource server are in a single application.

The following POST (with SoapUI) keeps failing:

```
http://localhost:8080/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=hans.wurst&password=bla&client_id=androidAppClient
```

I get the message

> Access is denied (user is anonymous);

Debug tells me that the following filters were applied:

```
Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  BasicAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]
```

**Authorization server:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
class AuthorizationServerConfiguration : AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var dataSource: DataSource

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var tokenStore: TokenStore

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private lateinit var authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager

    override fun configure(clients: ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer) {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource)
    }

    override fun configure(endpoints: AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer) {
        endpoints
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore)
    }

}
```

**Web security:**

```
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfiguration : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(USER_DETAILS_SERVICE)
    private lateinit var userDetailsService: UserDetailsService

    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun authenticationManagerBean(): AuthenticationManager = super.authenticationManagerBean()

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(web: WebSecurity) {
        web.debug(true)
    }

    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
    }

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
    }
}
```

**Resource server:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
class ResourceServerConfiguration : ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/registration", "/customer/check")
                .anonymous()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
    }

}
```

**User details service:**

```
const val USER_DETAILS_SERVICE = "userDetailsService";

@Transactional
@Service(USER_DETAILS_SERVICE)
class CustomerUserDetailsService @Autowired constructor(private val customerRepository: CustomerRepository) : UserDetailsService {

    @Throws(UsernameNotFoundException::class)
    override fun loadUserByUsername(username: String): UserDetails =
            customerRepository
                    .findCustomerCredentialsByUserName(username)
                    ?.let { User(it.userName, it.password, emptyList()) }
                    ?: throw UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find customer with username $username")
}
```

Comment: Can you try adding "/oauth/token", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access" in addition to "/registration", "/customer/check" in ResourceServerConfiguration?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that client `androidAppClient` doesn't have `password` grant type set in `authorized_grant_types`.

Check client details table in DB (`oauth_client_details`), make sure `password` grant type is set for this client. **If it is set along with other grant types then make sure there are no spaces in grant types like, (`'password,refresh_token')`.**

The `/oauth/token` endpoint's post request expects client credentials in Base64 "clientId:clientSecret" format.

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://localhost:8443/auth-service/oauth/token \
  --header 'authorization: Basic UkVXQVJEU19QT1QUxfQURNSU46cGFzc3dvcmQ=' \
  --header 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001' \
  --form username=testuser \
  --form password=password \
  --form grant_type=password
```

Comment: The client in oauth_client_details was fine. Using basic auth for client_id:client_secret worked and my request got authenticated. However, after that I'm getting a 404 response, even though in the log I can see that /oauth/token got mapped onto `TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken`.

Comment: Oh well, I figured it out. I'm using JAX-RS resources in Spring. This somehow interferes with the OAuth2 endpoints